# Possible for Detox framework to take a photo on simulator/emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, ios-simulator, detox

I haven't found any documentation from Detox or general conversation about this while researching, so I fear this might not be possible. Has anyone been able to take a photo with the camera app using the Detox testing framework? This would be while running on a simulator/emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yerp, [not possible](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/1800#issuecomment-565573289)... Solution is to mock the camera API.

Comment: This may be possible in the future, once we finish our rewrite, but no assurances. Best to mock you API for 100% consistent results.

Comment: @LéoNatan any progress on the possibility of this?

Comment: @benmneb I am no longer working at Wix and have no involvement with the development of Detox.